# Using responsive images with art direction

Tags: html, image, responsive-images

Is it possible to use responsive images, for fetching an appropriately sized image, along with art direction for displaying a different image on mobile?

I haven't seen any docs with an example of this, but I also haven't seen any docs saying you can't.

This is the simplified code that I thought might work but doesn't (the original is messy Liquid/Shopify code)

```html
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(max-width: 989px)" 
    srcset="
      image-one-300.jpg 300w,
      image-one-800.jpg 800w,
      image-one-1200.jpg 1200w,
      image-one-1800.jpg 1800w,"
    sizes="100vw"
    src="image-one_1800.jpg"
  >
  <img
  srcset="
    image-two-300.jpg 300w,
    image-two-800.jpg 800w,
    image-two-1200.jpg 1200w,
    image-two-1800.jpg 1800w,"
  sizes="100vw"
  src="image-two_1800.jpg"
  >
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I do separate images for mobile is to simply add some CSS and then split them out:

CSS:

```
.mobileOnly {display:none;}
.desktopOnly {display:block;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .mobileOnly {display:block}
   .desktopOnly {display:none;}
}
```

Then in the HTML, you have classes that you can add to elements:

```
<img class="desktopOnly" src="..." />
<img class="mobileOnly" src="..." />
```

The great thing about this is that you can use it for anything, including specific divs, text and much more!

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: That solution means both images are loading at once. So I applied lazy loading to both images to prevent the hidden image from loading. Although I don't want it lazy loading as it's in view on page load. But I tested it anyway. I performed 9 runs each on webpagetests.org. Time to interactive is 0.6sec faster and fully loaded is 0.7 slower (total time 16sec @ 9mbps). Probably falls in negligible differences with everything else happening. Not sure if it's better or worse. I'd still like to be able to use srcset properly with art direction.